# Random number each time on javascript loop

Tags: javascript, audio, random

Im trying to play a random audio file using howler.js and then reselect a different random file overtime it loops. I have it playing and looping but with the same file every time it loops. The only random selection is on initial load.

This is what I have:

```
    var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
    var sound1 = new Howl({
      src: ['audio/'+number+'.wav'],
      autoplay: false,
      loop: false,
      volume: 1.0,
    onend: function() {
    sound1.play()
     }
     });

sound1.play()
```

This happily plays one of 3 random wav files from audio folder but only selects randomly on load. The same file then loops infinitely.

Pretty new to javascript so any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: well, on end you're just playing sound again, not changing the number

Comment: Would you mind pointing me in the direction of how to change the number on end please ? Ive tried the random number generator within the onend function but doesn't work

Comment: `number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);` again in `onend`.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Thats what I thought , but it doesn't work. Same file as initial load keeps playing.

Comment: There will also need to be an update to the *src* attribute. Just changing *number* doesn't do anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
var sounds = [];

function playRandom() {
  // play a random member of sounds
  sounds[Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length) + 1].play();
}

// load all the sounds ahead of time    
var numberOfSounds = 3;
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfSounds; i++) {
  sounds.push(new Howl({
    src: ['audio/' + i + '.wav'],
    autoplay: false,
    loop: false,
    volume: 1.0,
    onend: function () {
      // when one sound ends, play a new random one
      playRandom();
    },
  }));
}

// kick things off with the first random sound    
playRandom();
```

**UPDATE**

Answering the comment below, here's one way to play each sound four times repeatedly before moving on to the next random sound:

```
var sounds = [];

function playRepeatedly(sound, howManyTimes, callback) {
  // this is similar to using `onend` when you create the sound
  sound.once('end', function () {
    // if there are more repetitions to go
    if (howManyTimes > 1) {
      // play one less time
      playRepeatedly(sound, howManyTimes - 1, callback);
    } else {
      // if we're all done, call the callback
      callback();
    }
  });

  sound.play();
}

function playRandom() {
  // pick a random sound
  var sound = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length) + 1];

  // play it 4 times and then play a new random sound
  playRepeatedly(sound, 4, function () {
    // this is the callback, which just plays a new random sound
    playRandom();
  });
}

// load all the sounds ahead of time    
var numberOfSounds = 3;
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfSounds; i++) {
  sounds.push(new Howl({
    src: ['audio/' + i + '.wav'],
    autoplay: false,
    loop: false,
    volume: 1.0, // no more `onend` here
  }));
}

// kick things off with the first random sound    
playRandom();
```

Comment: Thats works perfectly thanks ! Now to learn what its doing ! Cheers

Comment: @dee Is there some part you're having particular trouble understanding?

Comment: Out of interest. Can you loop within a loop. SO for instance, is it possible to play the file say 4 times before moving on to the next random choice ?

Comment: Yes, you could do that... a few ways come to mind, but none of them contain a nested loop. :-)

Comment: @dee I added one possible solution for "play it 4 times before moving on."

Answer (score 0):

I've never used howler.js, but you'll be able to just call it again onend. Just create a function that gets called when the sound stops playing:

```
function playSound(number) {
    var num = generateRandomNumber(number);
    var sound1 = new Howl({
        src: ['audio/' + num + '.wav'],
        autoplay: false,
        loop: false,
        volume: 1.0,
        onend: function() {
            playSound(num)
        }
    });

    sound1.play()
}

function generateRandomNumber(number) {
    var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
    // if it's the same number as in the previous round, get a new number
    while (number == num) {
        return generateRandomNumber(number);
    }
    return num;
}
```

Comment: Cheers,looks interesting....think i can see what its doing.  but that doesn't play anything at all.

Comment: You have to call the function... @dee

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the value of *number* and change the *src* attribute of the *Howl* instance, or just create a new one. Something like the following should work:

```
function createHowl() {
  var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
  return new Howl({
           src:      ['audio/' + number + '.wav'],
           autoplay: false,
           loop:     false,
           volume:   1.0,
           onend:    function() {createHowl().play()}
  });
}

createHowl().play();
```

Note that there's a 33% chance it will play the same sound twice in a row.

Answer (score 0):

first,You need to test on the server.I used chrome49.
my test code as follows：

```
var obj = new Options();
    var sound1 = new Howl(new Options());
    sound1.play();
    function Options()
    {
        var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
        this.src = ['audio/'+number+'.wav'];
        this.autoplay=false;
        this.loop=false;
        this.volume=1.0;
        this.onend = function(e) 
        {       
            new Howl(new Options()).play();
        }
    }
```

if the browser error "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Unable to decode audio data"，Your file format is incorrect.